# Add members to object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, object

I have an object created by - `new {name1 = "string1"}`
I have to add additional members to it eg `{name2 = "string2"}` so that the final result is

`{
name1 = "string1",
name2 = "string2"
}`

Comment: So...what's the question exactly?

Comment: I need to add additional name value pairs to the existing object in c# @MikeH

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a collection - like a `List<T>` or an array.

Comment: Or maybe just a dictionary...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Good point.  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context to your question?  Are you dealing with anonymous types or JSON or something else?

Comment: I am using SmartFormat .Net library [link](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET) . It accepts ("String",obj) to be passed to format the string. However, I already have this ("String", obj) and I need to add some more field values in the obj

Comment: Eg: Smart.Format(" Your Name is {Name}, new { Name = "someName"}. Need to add for eg {Age = "10"} to the above object.

Answer (score 2):

You can either instantiate it all at once:

```
var someObj = new {name1 = "name 1", name2 = "name 2"};
```

Or you can do it in steps.

```
var someObj1 = new {name1 = "name 1"};
var someObj2 = new {name1 = someObj1.name1, name2 = "name 2"};
```

But no, you can't add properties/field to anonymous types at run-time or after it's been instantiated.

Comment: someObj1 already has some items (count - unknown). And I need to add some new items. 
Also, the members present in it is unknown (name1, or something else)

Comment: You can either do something like `var someObj2 = new {firstObj = someObj1, name2 = "name 2"};` and then access the values from the new child type, declare the anonymous type with all of it's values at once, or use a Dictionary<string,obj> instead of an anonymous type as that seems more appropriate for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new object, of a new anonymous type:

```
var obj1 = new {name1 = "string1"};
var obj2 = new {name1 = obj1.name1, name2 = "string2" };
```

Comment: It doesnt allow me to access obj1.name1.
Also the number of items already presen tin obj1 is unknown @jakub-lortz